# How to fix rig merging pants?

Tags: modeling

So I'm trying to pose the legs of my rig, and it just merges the two legs together, what I mean is, it merges the clothes of them together.[image: Helpme]

Answer (score 1):

Go to Edit mode, select all vertices of left side, in the vertex group properties tab select all vertex groups (one after one) related to the right side and press the "Remove" button.

Repeat for right side.

If some harsh bending appears, use the smooth brush in weight paint mode on all affected vertex groups.

[image]

Comment: The problem is the pants are joined together when rigging and i can't really move them in edit mode